# Angular5 PrimeNG Datatable on a Modal with ContextMenu showing up behind the modal

Tags: css, angular, angular5, contextmenu, primeng

[image]

I have a modal window that contains a PrimeNG Datatable enabled with ContextMenu.
The problem is that when I right click one of the table rows, my right click context menu is behind the modal window. I've added appendTo="body" but that did not help except for correct positioning. The main problem now is that the context menu has a z-index that is BEHIND the modal.

I have tried explicitly setting the z-index but could not override the dynamically generated CSS that is applied to the context menu with every right click.

Any ideas, please?

Comment: Try adding baseZIndex for the context-menu which is greater than the modal and setting [autoZIndex]="false" i haven't try it but i hope it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the base z-index property of the context menu.

```
<p-contextMenu #cm [model]="items" appendTo="body" baseZIndex="99999"></p-contextMenu>
```

[here is stackblitz implementation](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cavzbl)

Comment: Works perfect!! Thank You. This was so hard to find and I have no idea why